# Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open - serverless framework

Tags: serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy my lambda functions using serverless framework.
I'm pretty sure it worked in the past, now I get the error below when calling `sls deploy`.

The lambda runtime is in python. Here my last version of [serverless.yaml](https://github.com/antessio/dynamoplus/blob/feature/35-aggregation-queries/serverless/serverless.yml)

I'm running the deploy from macOS big sur but I get the same error from centos.

Any clue?

```
Error ---------------------------------------------------
 
  Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/Users/antoniodalessio/personal/dynamoplus-project/dynamoplus/serverless/.serverless/get.zip'
 
     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          darwin
     Node Version:              17.3.0
     Framework Version:         2.69.1 (local)
     Plugin Version:            5.5.1
     SDK Version:               4.3.0
     Components Version:        3.18.1
```